# JSP Model 2 Architecture and Dependency Injection

Tags: java, dependency-injection

If I'm writing a web application that uses the model 2 architecture, is it possible to use the Google Guice framework (or really any IoC container)? The reason I ask this question is because everything I've researched about DI, IoC, et cetera always uses Spring, Hibernate or some other framework/container in their examples. I'm just using Java classes, controllers, and JSP's to build this application and I can't find any good documentation about the subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you're looking for in the Java EE web tier is a technology called CDI, a tutorial on this can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbnz.html)